# Execute Stored Procedure in Azure Logic App - Bad gateway error

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

When I execute the stored procedure from logic app designer, I'm getting bad gateway error.

The stored procedure which I'm trying to call

```
create procedure test as select * from testable
```

test table contains 100000+ rows.

The results of stored procedure are placed in Blob/FTP.

error

> Duration: 0s
>
> Start time: 2017-08-11T17:37:57.8096605Z
>
> End time: 2017-08-11T17:37:58.0909952Z
>
> Status: BadGateway

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: try this link .this shows you how to troubleshoot errors and then update your question ,if you face any issues:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503

Comment: Please update your question with more details, what trigger do you use? Is the connection works?

Answer (score 0):

**Check those thinks**
1. Check the connection with DB.
2. If you put proxy to DB check and wite list the IP.
3. Check you SP code is it working properly in local.
4. The check did you select DB if you have many DB.
5. Check the Sp run time from the local DB and do the time out.